# What does "Cost" mean in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm reading a book about `Distributed Systems (Computer Engineering)`.

I faced with following context :

> Full transparency will ***cost performance***, exposing distribution of
>   the system

What does "Cost" mean?

Comment: It will influence the performance in a negative way - _It will cost you some performance_

Comment: cost v.tr. 2. To cause to lose, suffer, or sacrifice: Participating in the strike cost me my job. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full transparency will **negatively impact** performance.  It is an example of "you can't get something for nothing."

The writer could also have used "decrease performance" or "reduce performance" or "degrade performance", but using "cost" is an allusion to the concept of **Cost / Benefit** trade-off.

Comment: quite identical to my comment.

Comment: @mplungjan  We could also use **decrease** or perhaps **degrade**